# OpenShift oc command line with Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, openshift

I'm running Cygwin 64bit but can't seem to get OpenShift oc command line to work

I downloaded oc.tar.gz ( from here https://mirror.openshift.com/pub/openshift-v3/clients/3.6.173.0.5/linux/oc.tar.gz ), unzipped it and placed it in my path in /usr/bin

When I try to run: oc login I get the following.

-bash: /usr/bin/oc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Do I need to somehow 'install' the executable ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Graham Dumpleton's answer:

open cygwin and check for directory /usr/local/bin
mkdir -p local/bin

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
```

if it does not exists:

`$ mkdir -p local/bin`

finally extract the **windows package**:

```
$ cp /cygdrive/c/Users/me/Downloads/oc-3.5.5.31.24-windows.zip /usr/local/bin/
unzip oc-3.5.5.31.24-windows.zip


$ oc version
oc v3.5.5.31.24
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
features: Basic-Auth
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Windows binary from the following page:

- https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases

Answer (score 1):

From project homepage
https://www.cygwin.com/

> Cygwin is not:
>
> a way to run native Linux apps on Windows. You must rebuild your
>   application from source if you want it to run on Windows.
>
> a way to magically make native Windows apps aware of UNIX®
>   functionality like signals, ptys, etc. Again, you need to build your
>   apps from source if you want to take advantage of Cygwin
>   functionality.

Comment: Is it possible? Do you have experience with the OpenShift oc command line tool or are you just speaking in general about Cygwin?

Comment: A lot of experience about cygwin. `Exec format error` is very clear, you are trying to run a Linux program on a Windows system (cywin programs are windows specifically crafted programs)

Comment: Ok thanks, hopefully someone else can suggest a workaround or a perhaps a specific build for Cygwin